# How to change an objects values through methods in a different class Java

Tags: java

So I'm trying to edit an object's x value from a method in a different class. The real reason I'm doing this is far more complicated but I just wanted to simplify things.

I am creating a game and I want the object that belongs to the first Class to be updated throughout the game. However when I try to update it, it appears in the other class however as soon as scope is returned to the first class the x value remains 0.

I have been struggling with this for hours...

```
public class first {
    private second Second;

    public void view() {
        System.out.println(this.Second.x);
    }
    public void newObj() {
        Second = new second();
    }

    public void changeObj() {
        Second.changeX(4);
        Second = Second.getSecond();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    first First = new first();
    First.newObj();
    First.changeObj();
    First.view();
   }

}


public class second {

public static int x=0;

public second getSecond() {
    return this;
}

public second(){
    x=0;
}

public static void changeX(int x) {
    x = x;
    System.out.println(x);
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

}
```

Comment: Which `x` is which when you do `x=x`?

Comment: `x=x`? `this.x = x;`

Comment: Sorry for not clearing up but its; this.x = x;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're encountering this because of the way the assignment is done:

```
x=x;
```

Just doing this should trigger a warning message "The assignment to variable x has no effect". This is because you're not referring to the static variable `x` but the argument itself.

Each non-static variable exists in the context of an object. In this case `x` is static so the usage of `this.x = x;` in a static context is not possible either. The correct approach is

```
Second.x = x;
```

Comment: I get the error "Second cannot be resolved to a variable" if I change x=x; to Second.x = x;

Comment: @user3396971 `Second` should be the name of the class.. If you have provided example code and the name of the class is something else then use it instead of `Second`.

Comment: @user3396971 I see that in the code the name of your class is `second`. By java's naming conventions classes' names should always begin with a capital letter.

Comment: Thanks! I've realised what I was doing wrong. Your answer helped greatly!